# How to set a link different behavior for logged and non-logged user?

Tags: php

I want to set a link. If behaves differently for logged and non-logged users. If non-logged user click it, it will go to a login page. And if logged users click it, it will go to woocommerce my account page.
Suggest me right code please.

```
<?php

case 'login':
    if ( ! function_exists( 'WC' ) ) {
        break;
    }
    $toggle = is_user_logged_in() ? 'link' : sober_get_option('account_icon_behaviour');
    printf('<li class="menu-item menu-item-account"><a href="%s" data-toggle="%s" data-target="login-modal"><svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><use xlink:href="#user-account-people"></use></svg></a></li>',
            esc_url( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( 'dashboard' ) ),esc_attr( $toggle ));
    break;
```

Comment: you just need to make a link to woocommerce "my account". if the customer is not logged in, this page show a login form.

Comment: Please edit your question and copy-paste the code as a text, because as image we cannot reproduce your code

Comment: `case 'login':
if ( ! function_exists( 'WC' ) ) {
break;
}
$toggle = is_user_logged_in() ? 'link' : sober_get_option( 'account_icon_behaviour' );
printf(
'<li class="menu-item menu-item-account"><a href="%s" data-toggle="%s" data-target="login-modal"><svg viewBox="0 0 20 20"><use xlink:href="#user-account-people"></use></svg></a></li>',
esc_url( wc_get_account_endpoint_url( 'dashboard' ) ),
esc_attr( $toggle )
);
break;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress has a function for this, called [`is_user_logged_in`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/). You use it like this:

```
if (is_user_logged_in())
  echo '<a href="account page">link text</a>';
else
  echo '<a href="login page">link text</a>';
```